# Вырезать текст до определённого символа

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет.

Как получить часть текста, находящуюся до дефиса? Моя регулярка через `preg_replace` выдаёт какой-то кусок текста + ещё присутствует сломанная кодировка. Пробовал так

```
( ([а-яА-ЯёЁ0-9 - ]*)).*
```

[Вот](https://regex101.com/r/IJn3zv/1) здесь есть пример текста.

Comment: " (.*) - .*" - ? (без двойных кавычек)

Comment: Не сработало. Он ни чего не выделил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать опережающий просмотр:

```
$str = ' Термин 1 - Очень больше описание
 Термин 2 - Очень больше описание
 Термин 3 - Очень больше описание
 Термин 4 плюс ещё одно слово - Очень больше описание
 Термин 5 - Очень больше описание
 Термин 6 - Очень больше описание
 Термин 7 - Очень больше описание';

preg_match_all('~.+(?=-)~', $str, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

---

Или с помощью preg_replace() и ссылок на подмаски:

```
$str = ' Термин 1 - Очень больше описание
 Термин 2 - Очень больше описание
 Термин 3 - Очень больше описание
 Термин 4 плюс ещё одно слово - Очень больше описание
 Термин 5 - Очень больше описание
 Термин 6 - Очень больше описание
 Термин 7 - Очень больше описание';

echo preg_replace('~(.+)\s?-.*~', '$1<br>', $str);
```

Comment: А как это сделать через функцию preg_replace?

Comment: @LexXy отредактировал ответ. Но лучше __выбирать нужное__, а не __удалять лишнее__

Comment: Сработало! Спасибо!

Comment: А почему лучше "выбирать", а не "удалять"?

Comment: @LexXy потому что выбирая нужное вы гарантировано получаете необходимые подстроки. А вот удаляя лишнее, в случае изменения исходной строки, в результат могут попасть "лишние" элементы подстроки.

Comment: @Эдуард, лучше бы заменить `.+` на `.+?`, и времени будет затрачено меньше.

Comment: @Let'ssayPie Вообще-то `'~(.+)\s?-.*~'` не одно и то же, что (они не только по скорости разные) `'~(.+?)\s?-.*~'`, ленивый квантификатор добавит смысл `\s?`, т. к. `'~(.+)\s?-.*~'` = `'~(.+)-.*~'`.